# stepper motor rpm speed with different step angles

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, stepper-motor

I am wondering if two stepper motors with different step angles - one 0.9 degrees, other 1.8 degrees would have the same speed (rotations per minute). I assume all other parameters are the same.

Someone told me the 0.9 degree motor would be half the speed but it does not sound logical, as I assume the only difference is that motor with 0.9 would need double pulses to achieve the same speed as 1.8 degree motor.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Provided that the motor can move as fast for other reasons.

Comment: Thank you - I think I understand now - the slower motor will require a controller that has double the pulse frequency to achieve the same speed, otherwise it will be half the speed as each pulse will produce half the movement.